# How to kill user processes from the same user?

Tags: linux, vnc, users

I opened a VNC server and my VNC session is suddenly dead. I have lot of xterms open.
When I ssh to the machine. and type

```
users
```

I see a bunch of users – my user accounts, like:

```
userA UserA UserA UserA UserA UserA UserA
```

I know I can use

```
pkill -u usersname
```

Since I can only log in as `userA`, every time I run `pkill-u UserA`, it will just kill my current session. but other userAs are still there

What can I do?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @Renan I *assume* he wants to kill those extra user sessions.

Comment: exactly. other sessions are not killed, but my current session is killed

Comment: @slhck That's what I assumed, too. But he edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A useful tools is `slay`: `sudo slay username`
If you don't run `slay` as root, you will end up killing off all of *your* processes however, rather than the specified user.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-do-i-kill-all-a-users-processes-using-their-uid

Answer (score 0):

Get all of userA's PIDs other than that of your current shell with:

```
/bin/ls -u userA | egrep -v "^ +$$"
```

(Note the double quotes in the `egrep` command.)  Then kill just those PIDs.  Your shell should remain.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
/bin/ls -u redmage
```

Just gave me:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access redmage: No such file or directory
```

However,

```
who -u
```

Told me who is logged in, and printed the associated pid, EG:

```
redmage  tty4         2012-06-09 22:05 00:01         695
bluemage  pts/1        2012-06-09 18:28   .          3466 (:0.0)
```

Then just kill -9; No more CPU time!

```
kill -9 695
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `pkill -u someusername` attempts to kill all processes from someusername.

What I think happens if you try to do this, is that you kill the processes from your own session succesfully, and fail to kill the other processes because you are not permitted to do so.

Though untested, I believe this should do the trick:

```
sudo pkill -u usersname
```